# How to suppress warnings when using boxplot()?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

When I use the boxplot(), I get 2 warnings.  The chart is displayed correctly, but 2 warnings appear.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
df.boxplot()
```

Here are the 2 warnings.

Warning 1:

```
  /home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ interactiveshell.py:2910: FutureWarning:


mpl_style had been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Use `matplotlib.pyplot.style.use` instead.
```

Warning 2:

```
 /home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/ font_manager.py:1320: UserWarning:

    findfont: Font family ['monospace'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
```

Is there anything I can do to suppress these 2 warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

instead of

```
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
```

Please import the matplotlib package before calling this.